# Prepare data for multioutput regression in Caffe

Tags: python, hdf5, deep-learning, caffe

I need to write python script that prepare data to feed it to a caffe solver.
My input is images(`X`) and vector of ints(`Y`) (I have multioutput regression problem not single `Y` for each `X`) and I try to modify Lenet to my task.

[Here](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231n/slides/caffe_tutorial.pdf) I found that hdf5 can be a good option - it can be used from python, but drawbacks is that we can't do data augmentation on-the-fly and input images must be float32/float64.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140000/how-to-feed-caffe-multi-label-data-in-hdf5-format) I found an example, but in example there is only 1D data, so I'm curious what shape images should have?

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057957/multi-label-regression-in-caffe) I found info about `EUCLIDEAN_LOSS` and `HINGE_LOSS` layers. What layer type should I use for multioutput regression?

Comment: please ask a **single** question at each post: one for data, and maybe a new one for what loss to use.

Comment: BTW using enum (e.g., `EUCLIDEAN_LOSS`, `HINGE_LOSS`) for layer type indicates old caffe version. Newer versions work with strings: `type: "EuclideanLoss"`, or `type: "HIngeLoss"`. Make sure your caffe branch is up to date.

Comment: How python-ic are you? you can write a `type: "Python"` layer as an input layer to do the augmentations you want on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Caffe expects its input images to be 4-D `B`-by-`C`-by-`H`-by-`W`:

- `B` is the "batch size", the number of images you process simultaneously
- `C` is the number of channels, usually 3 for BGR (most nets conforms to opencv BGR format, rather than RGB. go figure...)
- `H` and `W` are the height and width of the image, respectively.

Therefore, you need a python script that read images (you can use `caffe.io.load_image`) then transpose, resize, rescale and finally stack them into `B`-by-`C`-by-`H`-by-`W` numpy arrays of type `float32`.
You can do the augmentations in python and save all the data into `hdf5` files.

Comment: I don't understand, I need to feed data to caffe batch by batch manually or need to save it in hdf5 as `N`-`C`-`H`-`W` where `N` is number of samples/examples.

Comment: @mrgloom the data should be 4D in your HDF5 file. Each sample is of size `C`-`H`-`W` and you have `n1` of them stored in the file. When training, caffe reads only `B` of them at a time according to the `batch_size` you define. Thus, you can store many samples (much more than a single batch) in each `HDF5` file. However, the rest of the dimensions (`C`, `H` and `W`) should remain fixed throughout.